# Css Dropdown Menu bugging out

Tags: html, css

When you scroll at all down the page a sticky header replaces the original nav, if you try to use the second level dropdowns, most of them bug out like crazy and try to display the second dropdown right ontop of the first.  Any idea why this is happening?  It is the same code as the normal nav that works fine.

http://brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/expression/blog

Comment: Please post your code here and put together a jsFiddle. Linking to external sites isn't good practice, as once the issue has been fixed (either independently or through the help of someone on Stack Overflow) the question loses its meaning...

Comment: wow, that one is crazy